# File "main.py", line 3 this.ratings = [

Tags: python

File "main.py", line 3
this.ratings =[image: []

Comment: пожалуйста, НИКОГДА не добавляйте код картинкой. Скопируйте его и добавьте в вопрос текстом

Comment: Вы точно на Python пишите? Если да, то откуда тогда взялись фигурные скобки и `this`? Сейчас у вас какая-то смесь Python и JavaScript.